# Python OpenCV Error: (-215:Assertion failed) _step >= minstep in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to get python-opencv running, but I always get this error:

```
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:466: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _step >= minstep in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'
```

This path part is really strange "D:\a\opencv-" I never even had a D: drive.

This is my code (Windows 10, python 3.8, pycharm, pipenv)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pg


def make_screenshot(x=0, y=0, x_length=1920, y_length=1080, debug=False):
    image = pg.screenshot(region=(x, y, x_length, y_length))
    image = np.array(image)
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    if debug:
        cv.imshow('test', image)
        cv.waitKey()
    return image


print(make_screenshot(0, 0, 1, 1, False))
```

Checked already without success:

[error: (-215:Assertion failed) _step >= minstep in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177334/error-215assertion-failed-step-minstep-in-function-cvmatmat)

[error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize' OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61631851/error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cvresize-opencv)

[cv2.error:(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584934/cv2-error-215assertion-failed-src-empty-in-function-cvcvtcolor)

Comment: The path it reports in the error message is based on the machine where the library was compiled, it has nothing to do with your computer (unless you built the binaries yourself). Not sure where you got it from, but the name `4.5.4-dev` would suggest it being some sort of in-progress development build, so you're kinda on your own. Still the error message is kinda interesting since the code seems reasonable.

Comment: I installed it via `pipenv install opencv-python`
I will try to specify some older "stable" version and try again.
I think you might be right here because exactly the same code has worked for me before. I really should start defining fixed versions in my pipfile instead of '*'

Comment: `.copy()` the numpy array. OpenCV complains about the data having weird strides or something -- don't try any "older stable" version. get the freshest version at https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/, which you get with `pip install opencv-python` (not sure what pipenv does)

Comment: pipenv is a combination of pip and venv.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) copies by default. Not sure why that would produce something that OpenCV can't make sense of (I'm aware of the nuances of mapping numpy arrays to `cv::Mat`). The only difference against an explicit copy I see is that this function keeps the order (C or Fortran) same, and `ndarray.copy` forces it to C order (might be worth trying to override that behaviour). But still, why would PIL produce a Fortran order array, when this approach is one that has worked for ages now? Am I missing something?

Comment: that was just insufficiently disclaimed speculation on my part. -- this situation requires debugging, i.e. running this stuff, which I'm not motivated to do -- your link to `np.array` mentions a "bug" in the notes... I don't think that's happening here, but something is

Comment: interesting: same issue (same person?) https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/qdsno8/cant_get_opencv_running/ and I saw no other hits for this issue anywhere else. it can't be the first time someone tried pyautogui.screenshot with OpenCV... so it's probably some **new bug** (subset of {pyautogui, numpy, opencv}) and this person is the first to encounter it? this guy shows virtually identical code and I'm sure he ran it and it worked: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/01/taking-screenshots-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes that's me, I created the Reddit post first then a friend told me to post it on SO and I forgot to delete the post. 
I found a workaround for my problem. When I increase the size of my screenshot from 1x1 pixel to 2x2 it works again. (so `make_screenshot(0, 0, 2, 2, False)`)
The thing is 1x1 worked before, I don't understand why it does not work any more.

Answer (score -2):

Do you need to convert it to an array?

Maybe use the .imread() function as well.

```
image = cv2.imread(image)
```

Comment: I don't want to read the image from a file if I just screenshotted it and have it in memory.
I still tried it, and it throws the same error.

`Do you need to convert it to an array?`

Yes because to use an image in cv which was recorded by pillow it has to be formatted correctly and np.array and cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR does exactly that.